# Use friend function from another cpp

Tags: c++, function, friend-function

I need to define a function in my .hpp file, declare it in my .cpp file and then use it in a second .cpp file that includes the first one.

My problem is that when I do all this, I get the error: "example" was not declared in this scope.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, can someone please help me?

base.hpp

```
    class Base {
public:
    static size_t b;
    Base() {};
    friend Base exemple(uint64_t value);
};
```

base.cpp

```
Base exemple(size_t value)
{
  Base res;
  Base::b = value;
  return res;
}
```

in the main of my second cpp (stack.cpp)

```
exemple(3);
```

Comment: `Base::b = value;` What book has taught you to do this?

Comment: `Base` does not need a friend, all its members are public.

Comment: Do you really want `b` to be a static member? Looking at the example function it appears you don't.

Comment: @273K That's not the point, and it's my teacher who has several programming degrees and 40 years of experience.

Then, if the function doesn't need to be friended, why can't I access it even if I remove the "friend"?

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, b MUST be static. The function is only an example and is not finished. I'm trying to get access to it first :/

Comment: I'm not sure that making a function friend, declares it at the same time. You need to declare it outside of the class. But then function and class are co-depended, so maybe you'll get again a compilation error. It will help more if you post the errors.

Comment: **what I'm doing wrong** You should start with explaining what you see is wrong. Errors? Post them! Misbehavior? Post your expectations! And post a [mcve].

Comment: @273K I already post it... "error: "example" was not declared in this scope." is my error when I compile. I just want to use my function exemple() from my base.cpp in the main of my stack.cpp

Comment: Remove the friend, that is confusing you, it is not needed, since `b` is public. Then think about where you declare the function?

Comment: In stack.cpp, `example` cannot be find by name lookup. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend), *A name first declared in a friend declaration within a class X becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but is not visible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers X) unless a matching declaration at namespace scope is provided*. And the parameter type of `example` is only a primitive data type, so it cannot be found by ADL. You can try to add **another** normal declaration outside the class for `example` in base.hpp.